# Slow compile speed when initializing a container with ~7000 elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the following in a source file:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<UChar32>> table = {
    { 0x1234, 0xabcd },
    { 0x5678, 0xef01, 0xfe21},
    // ~7000 more elements omitted
};
```

and compile times with Visual Studio 2013 are extremely slow (I've waited 30 minutes on an i7-2600 before aborting). Is there some way to speed things up?

Edit: I should add that this source file only contains this definition, as well as the necessary includes. UChar32 is simply a typedef of std::int32_t.

Comment: Can you move the initial values into a file and write a routine to create the vector by reading the file?

Comment: I seriously suggest moving your input into a file such as an XML file or what not and loading that file dynamically.  That'll probably be your best bet of removing the performance degradation.

Comment: @godel9 yes I can, but I thought it would be a good idea to bake the data into the program. I didn't expect such slow compile times though.

Comment: I routinely initialize larger arrays than that (not vectors though) with VS2010 and compile times are quite fast. Maybe you'll have better luck with a good old array. Also you're likely to have better data locality by not allocating a lot of small vectors.

Comment: move the initialization to a separate source file. Then you will only have to recompile if those values are changed.

Comment: You have two bottleneck issues:  compilation and run-time initialization.  At compile time, the compiler (and linker) need to allocate space to put the data:  either in the executable or some space where constants are stored.  Secondly, when you program starts, the constant data is copied from the constant area into dynamic memory by `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is constant, initialized by compiler and not changed by the program, you will be better off by using an array.

Also, the data should be in a separate translation unit, so it is not compiled often.

This is a common technique in embedded systems for compiling fixed data such as bitmap fonts or language translation tables.

When you declare the array, declare it without size and as "static const" so that it won't be pushed onto the stack when it is used.

Comment: The inner container is of variable size. I'm under the impression that this excludes arrays.

Comment: If the longest inner container length is known and reasonable, you can do:  `const UChar32 table[][MAXINNER]= { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I did tests for nested initializer lists for const vector < vector < int > > of ~10k (total) elements and I consistantly get:

- 0.6s compilation time using default VC12 compiler
- 0.55s using VC13 CTP compiler

Ran on @2.4GHz i7 and SSD on Win8.1 x64.

So I thing that the problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the table in multiple places? Could that be the compiler treating this const like a macro and expending it somewhere else whenever encountered?

I doubt that be the case but that's a possibility...